# Is there a way to add local bson documents to mongodb using mongocxx driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a few bson files which i need to insert into the mongodb using c++ code.
Is there any way to insert a bson document into mongodb using mongocxx driver? 
I am using ubuntu, and all I could get was to manually create the document inside the code.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't have an API to manipulate BSON files, so you'll need to use an external tool:

- Use [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) to import your BSON files, you can launch it from your C++ code using `exec` or alike functions.
- Or you could use [`bsondump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/bsondump/) to create a JSON file from your BSON file and then insert it using the C++ driver, but as mentioned on the doc page: `bsondump is a diagnostic tool for inspecting BSON files, not a tool for data ingestion or other application use.`